# File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can successfully upload a file using MVC but when the file gets great a little bit I encountered the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404- File or Directory not found
```

This is my codes:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitProductCatTizer(MZPDB.ProductCatTizer model, long proCatId, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file == null)
                return RedirectToAction("AddProductCatTizer");

            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded/" + guid + ".mp4");
            file.SaveAs(fullPath);
            Dbcontex.ProductCatTizers.Add(new MZPDB.ProductCatTizer()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                ProductCatId = proCatId,
                VideoFile = guid,
                Status = true

            });
            Dbcontex.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ListProductCatTizer", "ListAdmin", new { area = "AdminPanel" });
        }
        return View("AddProductCatTizer");
    }
```

Comment: Hi fedora. I believe the answer you are looking for can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#unexpected-not-found-error-with-iis . Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS for hosting then configure your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!- 1 Gb ->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```